# php first element of the array isnt sorted

Tags: php

I try to sort the elements of an array in PHP .I explode the elements from a .txt file and all the elements are sorted EXCEPT the [0] indexed element.Why this happens in the code below?

```
$filemanaviki = fopen("manaviki.txt","r") or die ("Unable to open file!");
$anagnosi = fread($filemanaviki,filesize("manaviki.txt"));
$manaviki = explode(',',$anagnosi);
sort($manaviki);
$mikos=count($manaviki);
for($i=0; $i < $mikos;$i++){
    echo "<p id='testing' onclick='createNew(this.innerHTML);'>{$manaviki[$i]}</p>";
}

?>
```

in the .txt file i have those values

```
Πατάτες,Λάχανο,Κρεμμύδι,Πιπεριές,Φασολάκια,Γίγαντες,Ντομάτες
```

Comment: How exactly should we guess what's in `$manaviki`?

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: all of that fopen/fread/explode business could be replaced with a simple `$manaviki = file('manaviki.txt')`. and a `var_dump($manaviki)` before/after the sort will show you what's happening.

Comment: @MarcB I think you meant `file_get_contents()`, since file() creates an array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: which is exactly what OP does. reads the file, explodes it to an array, then loops on the array.

Comment: Try asort instead of sort

Comment: @MarcB `file()` explodes it on newline, not on comma.

Comment: What's returned by `strlen($manaviki[0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `manaviki.txt` file is saved with *BOM characters* in top of it, to be recognised as UTF-8. Try by resaving your file `without BOM` character (efficiently interpreted as `ANSI as UTF-8` in programs like `Notepad++`) so the `sort` don't get confused with the strange characters in the top (BOM) which applied to first element.

Comment: No problem, thing is that i was in the middle of sometihng similar and came to my mind.

Comment: @Panagiotis Iliakopoulos, accept the answer if it suits you as well.

Comment: @Panagiotis Iliakopoulos, :), just tick the V symbol below the ^v symbols.